# How to adjust HMS Scan Kit CustomizedView scale in a fragment?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

I want to use CustomizedView inside a fragment that is not full screen. I found that the camera viewfinder looks stretched, I've tried to adjust the width and height but nothing works.
Here's the image comparison between CustomizedView in activity and fragment.

in fragment (stretched)
[image: in fragment (stretched)]

in activity (normal)
[image: in activity (normal)]

is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After inspecting the layout with the layout inspector, I found that the *layout_width* child view of the RemoteView is set to a specific value.
[TextureView width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NB3fv.png)

It can be solved with a workaround by finding the TextureView:

```
    private fun findTextureViewInChildren(viewGroup: ViewGroup): TextureView? {
        val childCount = viewGroup.childCount
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val child: View = viewGroup.getChildAt(i)
            if (child is TextureView) {
                return child
            } else if (child is ViewGroup) {
                val foundInViewGroup = findTextureViewInChildren(child)
                if (foundInViewGroup != null) {
                    return foundInViewGroup
                }
            }
        }
        return null
    }
```

and then setting the *layout_width* to *match_parent*:

```
val surfaceView = findTextureViewInChildren(this)

val layoutParams = surfaceView.layoutParams
layoutParams.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
surfaceView.layoutParams = layoutParams
```

Comment: it works! finally found the answer after a while. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the code in the FrameLayout in the Activity_defined.xml file as I have given below, the problem will be solved.

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/rim"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="55dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"></FrameLayout>
```

Especially;

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

You should pay attention to the changes in the parts. (When making changes, FrameLayout dimensions should be changed in proportion to the screen dimensions.)

Unless you reduce the phone screen size and Camera Frame layout to match proportionally, you will continue to experience this problem. With the change you make, you are breaking the ratio of the camera to the phone screen and unfortunately, the image is distorted.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer! yeah, it works using your code, but that's not what i want to achieve. i want to embed the camera view to a fragment that the size can be dynamic, not always in full screen. 

so, it basically really depends on the screen size, is there any way to reduce the screen size as you mentioned? maybe by overriding some value from the hms camera view